# WebLogic12C - The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: jsp, weblogic12c, java-8

I'm dealing with a legacy servlet code that runs on WebLogic 10.3.6 (JDK 1.6).

I am trying to compile this code with JDK 1.8 and weblogic 12.2.1.0. 
When i am trying to compile the jsp page with jdk 1.8, i am seeing the following error. I tried the below options to fix this problem
 1) i tried Dynamic includes for JSP
 2) I tried adding

```
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
...
<init-param>
    <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
...
```

Both didnt work for me. Could you please help me with this. I am struggling for this error from last 2 days. But didn't get any solution yet.

<2017-02-02T16:21:30.723> <111>  MainServlet.doProcess(Request, Response): Error while processing the HTTP request
 --- javax.servlet.ServletException: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /main/campaign.jsp
campaign.jsp:22:1: The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

^-----
        HREF="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/include/css/moms_styles.css"
-------------^

```
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:310)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:625)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:282)
    at com.synapsegroupinc.mvc.controller.MainServlet.handleRequest(MainServlet.java:420)
    at com.synapsegroupinc.mvc.controller.MainServlet.doProcess(MainServlet.java:264)
    at com.synapsegroupinc.mvc.controller.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:197)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.synapsegroupinc.moms.util.web.model.MomsUserContextFilter.doFilter(MomsUserContextFilter.java:116)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to split the jsp page and use include jsp. It will reduce the lines of code and size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that code is very old code (which was written in 2002) . And we can't split the page as it has more components in it. is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: you can split the jsp without break the existing function right. means you still bring the component to the small jsp. and make sure after split your code still working.

Comment: yea, Sure i will try to do that. Is there any patches available for that issue in weblogic 12c ? When i checked online, there are some patches available for the weblogic 12.1.2. But i am using web logic 12.2.1

Comment: here they mentioned about the patches for that error. We downloaded that patches from oracle account and tried it. But those patches are for 12.1.2 version , unfortunately we are using 12.2.1 version of web logic.                     http://www.javamonamour.org/2016/12/weblogic-jsp-generation-and-compilation.html

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug that has been reported at oracle.

> Bug 25294832 : WLS 12.2.1.2 DEPLOYMENT ERRORSMETHOD _JSPSERVICE EXCEEDS 65535 BYTES LIMIT

Please use the bug id and support.oracle.com to get a resolution for this.